# Extract files to a different folder

Tags: windows-xp, compression, 7-zip

On a Windows XP machine, I have a zip file located on `"c:\temp\mydata\okidata.zip"`. Using 7-Zip application, I would like to write a batch script and extract the file silently to the following location `"c:\printers\okidata"`.  How should I write the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 7-Zip from the command line, as you suspect by using the following command:

`7z x "c:\temp\mydata\okidata.zip" -o"C:\printers\okidata"`

Where:  `x` = extract (keeping paths), and `-o` = output directory.